# Can't install drupal commerce with composer error

Tags: drupal, commerce, drupal-commerce

```
can't install commerce by use composer, I tried both command :

composer require drupal/commerce
composer require 'drupal/inline_entity_form:^1.0@RC
```

when I used "composer require drupal/commerce" I got error :

"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires drupal/commerce ^2.32 -> satisfiable by drupal/commerce[2.32.0].
- drupal/commerce 2.32.0 requires drupal/inline_entity_form ^1.0@RC -> found drupal/inline_entity_form[dev-1.x, 1.0.0-alpha1, ..., 1.x-dev (alias of dev-1.x)] but it does not match your minimum-stability.

Then I try to install inline-entity-form by used : composer require 'drupal/inline_entity_form:^1.0@RC'

then I got another error :
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Package symfony/debug is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/error-handler instead.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
[RuntimeException]
Could not delete /home/aaa/public_html/web/sites/default/default.services.yml:

```
Please advise what to do, thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are installing some modules that are, probably, available only in “release candidate” versions.
If that’s the case, you probably have to configure “**composer.json**” to allow “RC” versions.

Try changing

```
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

to

```
"minimum-stability": "RC"
```

Other options might be “beta”, “alpha”, “dev”, etc.